# Trying to query SQL database and format output that would insert into new db

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

So I have a local database and one in azure and I want to copy the data from one to the other, but can't figure out how to connect them. I figured the next best option would be to output my local data into an INSERT INTO command.

So basically, instead of having an output that shows the columns and data (ala 'Select top 1000 rows'), I'd like it to be formatted as such:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Articles(Id, Title, Thumbnail, VideoLink, Developer, Publisher, ReleaseDate, PublishDate, ReviewConsole, Score, Description, Text)
VALUES('Id','title','thumb','VidLink','dev','pub','release','publish','console','score','description','text'),
('Id2','title2','thumb2','VidLink2','dev2','pub2','release2','publish2','console2','score2','description2','text2'),
...
GO
```

Would anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ you should be looking at this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/mysql/concepts-migrate-dump-restore.md#user-content-create-a-backup-file-from-the-command-line-using-mysqldump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to get all the records with insert statements and column names like you want is to use the "Generate Scripts" option in Sql Management Studio. I'm using the 2016 version.

Right click on your database and select "Generate Scripts"-

[image]

In the next step select the tables you're interested in -

[image]

In the next step, select advanced option

[image]

In the next step select Data Only (unless you want to script the schema as well)

[image]

At the end, you should be able to get scripts like you're looking for.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much!